# Can I disable the metro-style settings menus in windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, modern-ui

Sorry in advance for my use of incorrect terminology.

Before Windows 8/10 there used to be a single menu for most settings. For example, if I wanted to change the mouse settings, I would go to the control panel or search "mouse" and get a mouse settings menu that looked more or less similar to this:

[image]

On Windows 10, there are these awkward half-finished menus that I now have to get through to get to the "actual" menu. For example, if I want to get to the mouse settings menu, I type "mouse" in the search bar, then I see something like this:

[image]

Clicking that button takes me to a menu that contains what appears to be a subset of the actual settings:

[image]

The rationale for these menus is lost on me as the settings offered are usually not what one looks for visiting them. In the case of the mouse settings I'm usually there to adjust the pointer speed, but the menu only offers settings on scroll behaviour and handedness.

The result is that I now just assume the menu is going to be useles, and immediately look for a link to the "actual" menu, which is sometimes difficult to find as there doesn't seem to be a consistent way to get past these "bad" menus. In this case it's the **Additional mouse options** link.

Whenever I need to modify some settings now, my workflow consists of one of two bad options:

1. take advantage of the search functionality, but then wade through the "bad" menus to get to the "good" one, or
2. go to the control panel and find the "good" menu item manually.

Is there a way that I can just type "mouse settings" in the search bar and get the "good" mouse settings?

Answer (score 1):

**GOD MODE**

ALL the settings in Control Panel at your Finger clicks.

Right-click your desktop and create a new folder.
Copy/Paste/Type

GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}

No spaces allowed

---

[The Hacker News](https://thehackernews.com/2015/10/windows10-godmode.html)

If you are a long-time Windows user, you might remember a trick called, 'God Mode'.
(A.K.A. Windows Master Control Panel Shortcut)

God Mode is an inbuilt, but hidden feature of Windows that provides additional customization 
options for the operating system.

With Windows 10, all the Settings of the operating system are kept under Settings App, and 
categorized between System, Devices, Network & Internet, Personalization, Update & Security, 
Privacy and more.

Enabling God Mode, also known as 'Windows Master Control Panel Shortcut', in Windows 10 
essentially unlocks a backdoor of the OS to access 260+ additional settings from a single folder.

#### How to Enable God Mode in Windows 10?

Follow the steps given below to enable the God Mode in your Windows 10:

1. Create a new folder on your Windows desktop (New > Folder) and save it with the name:

   GodMode.{ED7BA470-8E54-465E-825C-99712043E01C}
2. The folder's icon will change to an icon as of a Control Panel. Double-click on the new icon to see 
   your universal settings panel.
3. You can name the folder other than "GodMode"; before the Period (.).
4. Now, click the folder, open it and get god-like access to more than 260 functions and tools.

Some functions are unique to Windows 10 while others are similar to the previous versions of Windows.

#### How to Use God Mode?

You can drag and drop any of the commands to your desktop in order to create a shortcut for the command, 
but it will be pinned to the Start screen.

**The average user probably wouldn't use this feature.**

This source   https://thehackernews.com/2015/10/windows10-godmode.html

Comment: These instructions are not legible

Comment: @quant  I have updated my post, how is this?

Comment: Note that what you name it prior to the GUID is not important, "GodMode.", "Settings.", etc. will all work... the GUID is what's important.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Yes, thanks, I know, it is really called All Task or something like that in the Windows Registry. btw, this post is from Dec. 2019.

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way I know to get to the old mouse control panel is:

```
control.exe main.cpl
```

Press the Windows key and type the above or create a shortcut for it.

Settings in Windows 10 are still a mess, as you noticed the new Windows 10 settings app is missing many configuration items.

I think over time you want to migrate all old control panel settings into the new app, but even after over 4 years there are still many missing.

If `control.exe main.cpl` is too long for you, put it into a text file: `C:\windows\m.cmd` (or anywhere else as long as `%path%` points to it)

now you can type `m.cmd` into your search box.